# Performance impact on Class Loading VS Interface Loading in Java 8

Tags: class, interface, java-8, static-methods

I want to create a common functionality across many classes. 
SO I have 2 approaches. 
1) Create a new class and have a static method in it.
2) Create a new interface and have a concrete static method in it.

Can anyone explain the difference with respect to performance on both these approaches? 
Please consider both memory and processing impact.

Which approach should I choose and why?

Comment: `Create a new method and have a concrete static method in it`? what?

Comment: I assume you actual mean “2) Create a new **interface** and have a concrete static method in it.” In this case, there is no reason why there should be any notable performance difference.

Comment: Corrected the question. Thanks Eugene  and Holger.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise it should not matter, meaning that even if it is, it would be extremely small; so this should never drive your decision.

On the other hand defining an interface with a static method *that is solely used for common code* is a big code smell IMO. static methods in interfaces are usually defined so that they return an instance of this interface; I tend to look at them as static factory methods that *usually* return instances of themselves, like `Predicate#isEqual`:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return (null == targetRef)
            ? Objects::isNull
            : object -> targetRef.equals(object);
}
```

Besides that an interface purpose is still to be extended, if you write a simple static method inside it, you are sort of breaking that rule.

Another problem is that when you define a static method in an interface, classes that extend this interface can not use that method. Unlike default methods for example. So if you have an interface:

```
interface Test {
    public static String test() {
        return "";
    }

    public default String testAgain() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And a class `TestImpl` that extends this interface, than:

```
 TestImpl ti = new TestImpl();
 ti.testAgain();
 ti.test(); // will not compile
```

So may be you can use a default method instead of static. I sometimes favor this because it keeps the code closer to where I need it: if a certain class implements an interface with a `default method` - the code is right there, I don't need to use an external class.

static utility classes on the other hand are present all over the jdk for example, like `Collections`, `Streams` or `Spliterators` and that is what I would use if I were in your shoes.